# FQL query returning empty array

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm just getting started with developing with using facebook api with php.
But I can't seem to figure out why I get only an empty array when I invoke the following query:

```
$fql = "SELECT message,time FROM status WHERE uid ='".$uid."'";

$response = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' =>$fql));

print_r($response);
```

When I use a different query like the following I'm getting result back:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='".$uid."'";
```

Answer (score 6):

There may be an issue with permissions. You may need to grant `user_status` permission.

See here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: Hey I think that's most likely the issue. I'll try it out. Thanks Taras!

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions. A great way to do this is to use the [FQL Query Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=15723417%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname). Its great to test queries and the permissions you will need to access the data you are querying

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem, just instead I use:

```
{
"id":"SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()",
"posts":"SELECT message, time FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #id) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 50"
}
```

As a result I get:

```
    {
  "name": "posts", 
  "fql_result_set": [
  ]
}
```

If I change uid2 to uid1: `(SELECT uid1 FROM #id)`
I get my status updates.

2 weeks ago, this was working.

Permissions, in my case are correct.

Note: Query's are in Graph Explorer format, so they can be easyly tested